# mapply through columns and rows at the same time in R

Tags: r, sapply, mapply

I have a data frame column with born dates and one vector with 1200 date periods (valuation dates). I want to calculate the age of each born date in the 1200 periods. I have a solution but I think that it is weird.

Age function:

```
age <- function(born_date, valuation_date){

  if(any(!inherits(born_date, c("POSIXt", "POSIXct", "POSIXlt", "Date"))) | 
     any(!inherits(valuation_date, c("POSIXt", "POSIXct", "POSIXlt", "Date"))))
    stop("Born date or valuation date is not in POSIXt or Date format")

  round(as.double(valuation_date - born_date)/365.25)
}
```

Born Dates in df$FNACIMI:

```
df <- structure(list(FNACIMI = structure(c(-4216, -188, -4124, -2750, 
-2113, -95, 3840, -3629, 2321, 1629, -7547, -2883, -9987, -5078, 
-895, -848, 3069, -5134, -3778, -3647, -1573, 2156, -3250, -8277, 
-2516, -1829, -2448, -4658, -5731, -3554), class = "Date"), PRIMA_ANUAL = c(360, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 720, 720, 100, 1200, 1200, 0, 1020, 0, 0, 0, 2100, 
0, 0, 1200, 3000, 0, 0, 0, 8000, 1500, 0, 360, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("FNACIMI", 
"PRIMA_ANUAL"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

My solution is:

```
  result <- sapply(1:1200, flowDates)

  flowDates <- function(i) {
    mapply(fluxDates, df$FNACIMI[1:30], i)
  }

  fluxDates <- function(x, y){
    dates <- seq(as.Date("2017-08-31"), by = "month", length.out = 1200)
    mapply(age, x, dates[y])
  }
```

As we can see, there is a mapply inside another mapply and inside a sapply. Is there any more elegant way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data.

Comment: I added the df with the born dates, the periods vector is inside fluxDates(): dates <- seq(as.Date("2017-08-31"), by = "month", length.out = 1200)

Comment: `lapply(dates,function(x) as.numeric(difftime(x,df$FNACIMI,unit="weeks"))/52.25)` should to the trick.

Comment: Following your example: `sapply(dates,function(x) age(df$FNACIMI,x))`, but I don't understand why doesn't work with mapply: `mapply(age, df$FNACIMI, dates)`